# Janus gateway fails to fetch video stream from RTSP stream while gstreamer and VLC streams it easily

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, janus-gateway

As the title indicates using gStreamer or VLC I can get the video to show without issues with the command below

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=tcp location="rtsp://{USER}:{PASSWD}@{URL}:63554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! fpsdisplaysink`

I can set it as a Network Stream in VLC as below with similar results

`rtsp://{USER}:{PASSWD}@{URL}:63554/axis-media/media.amp?stream=0&videocodec=h264`

but janus (latest/stable: v0.11.3) configuration as below is unable to show the stream on the webpage

```
        type = "rtsp"
        id = 99
        description = "RTSP Test"
        audio = false
        video = true
        url = "rtsp://{USER}:{PASSWD}@{URL}:63554/axis-media/media.amp?stream=0&videocodec=h264"
        videortpmap = "H264/90000"
        videofmtp = "profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1"
        videoopt=96 
        secret = "adminpwd"
```

The error (repeatig) is as shown below

```
2021-09-18T10:20:56Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: [rtsp-test] Reconnected to the RTSP server, streaming again
2021-09-18T10:20:56Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: [rtsp-test] 30s passed, sending OPTIONS
```

and also

```
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: * Connection #0 to host {IP} left intact
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: SETUP answer:RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: CSeq: 2
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=10092-10093;server_port=50000-50001;ssrc=E60B5F25;mode="PLAY"
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Server: GStreamer RTSP server
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Session: c7gVPWsPKB48EAYw; timeout=60
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Date: Sat, 18 Sep 2021 10:11:57 GMT
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: 
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]:   -- RTP port (video): 50000
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]:   -- RTCP port (video): 50001
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]:   -- SSRC (video): 3859504933
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]:   -- RTSP session timeout (video): 30000 ms
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: [WARN] No host address for the RTSP video stream, no latching will be performed
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: RTSP video latching: 0.0.0.0:50000
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]:   -- RTCP: 0.0.0.0:50001
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Sending PLAY request...
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: * Found bundle for host {IP}: 0x7f143c01cee0 [can pipeline]
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: * Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host {IP}
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: * Connected to {IP} ({IP}) port 63554 (#0)
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: > PLAY rtsp://{USER}:{PASSWD}@{URL}:63554/axis-media/media.amp?stream=0&videocodec=h264 RTSP/1.0
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: CSeq: 3
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Session: c7gVPWsPKB48EAYw
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: Range: npt=0.000-
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: 
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: < RTSP/1.0 200 OK
2021-09-18T10:21:02Z janus-gateway.janus-gateway[30166]: < CSeq: 3
```

For now I have to use gstreamer to capture the rtsp stream and send it as rtp to janus with

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc protocols=tcp location="rtsp://{USER}:{PASSWD}@{URL}:63554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004`

But that will probably keep a 24/7 stream and this can be problematic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Janus Gateway/Server just doesn't support [interleaved mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol#Embedded_(Interleaved)_Binary_Data). And with current implementation of RTSP support inside Janus Streaming Plugin (Curl based) it's almost impossible to add such support there.

Comment: Razor sharp diagnostic, thanks! I guess I can deploy janus-gateway directly on the production server in order to access the camera while avoiding CGNAT, firewalls and etc...